# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nameOfCity' of null at App.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When I compile my files and run in console log I get this error

```
enter code here
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nameOfCity' of null     at App.render
```

They all "meet" at App component(I am using 'create-react-app' pack from facebook). I presume that it should load first Form Container and in it logic set initial state to empty and then Weather info data comes. Or am I wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {FormContainer} from './containers/FormContainer';
import WeatherInfo from './components/WeatherInfo';

class App extends Component {

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <div className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h2>Weather App</h2>
    </div>
    <p className="App-intro">
      To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
    </p>
      <FormContainer label="Name of the city:"/>
      <WeatherInfo
          nameOfCity={this.state.nameOfCity}
          weatherDescription={this.state.weatherDescription}
          windSpeed={this.state.windSpeed}
          temperature={this.state.temperature}
          maxTemperature={this.state.maxTemperature}
          minTemperature={this.state.minTemperature}
      />
  </div>
);
}
}
export default App;
```

Form Container

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';

class FormContainer extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        cityName: '',
        nameOfCity:'',
        weatherDescription:'',
        windSpeed:'',
        temperature:'',
        maxTemperature:'',
        minTemperature:''
    };
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleCityName = this.handleCityName.bind(this);
}

handleFormSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const SendForm = {
        cityName: this.state.cityName
    };
    console.log(SendForm);
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/weather?q=${SendForm.cityName}&units=metric&APPID=********`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(results => {
            this.setState({
                nameOfCity: results.city.name,
                weatherDescription: results.list[0].weather[0].description,
                windSpeed: results.list[2].wind.speed,
                temperature: results.list[0].main.temp,
                maxTemperature: results.list[0].main.temp_max,
                minTemperature: results.list[0].main.temp_min
            });
        });
}

handleCityName(value) {
    this.setState({ cityName: value });
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}>
            <label>{this.props.label}</label>
            <SearchBar
                name="CityName"
                type="text"
                value={this.state.cityName}
                placeholder="search"
                onChange={this.handleCityName}
            />
            <button type="submit"
                    className=""
                    value='Submit'
                    placeholder="Search" />
        </form>

        </div>
    );
}
}

export {FormContainer};
```

Search bar component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const SearchBar = (props) => (
<div>
    <label>{props.label}</label>
    <input name={props.name} type={props.inputType} value={props.value} placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={(e)=>props.onChange(e.target.value)}/>
</div>
);

export default SearchBar;
```

and Weather Info component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const WeatherInfo = (props) => (
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>{props.nameOfCity}</li>
        <li>{props.weatherDescription}</li>
        <li>{props.windSpeed}</li>
        <li>{props.temperature}</li>
        <li>{props.maxTemperature}</li>
        <li>{props.minTemperature}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
);

export default WeatherInfo;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to read nameOfCity from this.state in App, but your App component does not hold state.

You can have FormContainer use context and render WeatherInfo as a child:

```
class FormContainer extends Component {
  ...
  static childContextTypes = {
    nameOfCity: React.PropTypes.string
  }
  getChildContext() {
    return {
      nameOfCity: this.state.nameOfCity
    }
  }
 render: () {
   ...
   </form>
   {this.children}
 }

}
```

App.jsx:

```
<FormContainer label="Name of the City:">
  <WeatherInfo />
</FormContainer>
```

WeatherInfo.jsx:

```
class WeatherInfo extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    nameOfCity: React.PropTypes.string
  }
  render: () {
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>{this.context.nameOfCity}</li>
        ...
  }
}
```

---

OR you can store state in App, and have FormContainer change App.state either by passing a prop, or by using context.

Comment: thanks for explanation, but i won't use context... They recommend in fb that developers don't use them

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring at `<WeatherInfo nameOfCity={this.state.nameOfCity}` because at this point you don't have `nameOfCity` in the `App` component state.

In your code, the `nameOfCity` variable is inside `FormContainer` component state. If you want to use it across the components, you should have the state at the `App` component.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is u r using `this.state` in `App component`, and in `App component` u didn't define any `state`, that's why it is throwing the error, `can't read Cannot read property 'nameOfCity' of null`, because `state` is `null`. U need to define `state` in `App component` and then pass this `state` values in `props` and use those values in other `component`.

Answer (score 0):

These type of error occurs when you try to use attributes of non existing data. In this case this.state don't have value i.e. its **null**. So make sure your **this.state** have desired value by some manipulation as per your functionality.